# Input vazio não pode receber valor zero

Tags: javascript, string, input

Estou com um formulário com mais ou menos 5 *inputs*, em determinado momento algum desses *inputs* vão ficar sem valor, e eu quero descobrir qual o menor valor entre eles, mas sempre que tem um ou mais *inputs* vazios ele retorna o valor 0 e indica que esse é o menor numero :(

Com os inputs eu estou formando uma string com

```
document.querySelectorAll("input").value;
```

Recebendo os valores do `input`, mas sempre que tem um `input` vazio uma das locações dos string recebe zero e o

```
Math.min();
```

calcula esse valor como menor valor na string...

Tem uma maneira de ignorar o input vazio e não coloca-lo na string? ou algo semelhante?

Comment: Você poderia colocar o html dos seus inputs?

Comment: Na verdade os inputs só tem a classe que estou usando no css, não coloquei mais nada

Comment: Eles são todos `type=text`?

Comment: na verdade é number, esta recebendo numeros, valores em reais, esta com a mascara de jquery para pegar a virgula e o R$ automaticamente

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode iterar os valores dos inputs, e a condição `if(item.value)` retorna verdadeiro se o input não for:

- vazio
- NaN
- undefined
- espaços em branco

Dessa forma os inputs não preenchidos não serão considerados no momento de obter o mínimo.

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input"); // obtem todos os inputs
var valores = []; // vetor para armanezar somente os valores. Esse vetor será usado para obter o minimo entre um conjunto de valores

// funcao que será chamada pelo botão verificar
function verificar(){
  // forEach itera os inputs do formulario
  inputs.forEach(item =>{  
    if (item.value) // se o valor do input for valido (não vazio, nem espacos em branco, nem NaN, etc
      valores.push(parseFloat(item.value)); // empilha (adiciona) na lista de valores
  });
  console.log(Math.min.apply(null, valores)); //usamos a função Math min para obter o menor valor de um conjunto de valores
}
```

```html
<input type="text" /><br/>
<input type="text" /><br/>
<input type="text" /><br/>
<button onclick="verificar()">Verificar</button>
```

Alguma documentação do [Math.min.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta rapaz, mas algumas coisas que você usou ai ficaram de fora do meu conhecimento... é na função "verificar" que você colocou a condição do input? pq depois que eu pego os valores do input, ele passa por uma função que faz uns calculos, e depois mostro o menor resultado possivel, é uma calculadora de preço de cervejas na verdade... ela calcula o menor preço por "ml" e da o resultado de qual cerveja é mais barata (pelo tamanho e pelo preço)

Comment: Opa, você editou,vou dar uma olhada...

Comment: Ainda não deu certo.. as duas variáveis que vc usou no começo eu fiz igual mas com outros nome, o que eu fiz foi copiar essa sua função e troca o nome das variáveis no meio da função, e não funfou :/

Comment: Se você puder criar um Fiddle com as partes relevantes do seu código fica fácil ajudar. https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: fiz um codepen... da uma olhada mas não sei se vai ajudar..[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ENPxGQ)

Comment: [JSfiddle] (https://jsfiddle.net/ajb02qdf/)

Comment: Lucas, esta aparecendo infinity por evitar de erro valor é corrige `alert(menorValor!='Infinity'?menorValor:0);`

Comment: Obrigado @KingRider, coloquei a validação sugerida: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VmeYxY.

Comment: Deu certo!! Valeu @LucasCosta... qual o segredo?? `parseFloat` ???

Answer (score 1):

Veja se o código abaixo te ajuda.

- Pego o botão do DOM
- Adiciono um evento de `click` que:

  - Pego todos os inputs
  - Como o retorno do `document.querySelectorAll()` é um`NodeList` não
    posso usar funções de array nele como `.map`, `.filter` e `.reduce`, então crio um novo array e populo ele ao iterar o `NodeList`
  - Durante a iteração eu ja aproveito e faço o `parseFloat` pois os valores dos `inputs` vem como `string`
  - Faço um `.filter` que me retorna apenas os número maiores que zero e diferente de `NaN`
  - Chamo `Math.min` usando o `.apply` pois por padrão o `Math.min` não aceita um array como parâmetro, N números como parâmetros. Então o `.apply` deixa eu passar o escopo da função como primeiro parâmetro e no segundo parâmetro eu dou um array que será inserido como parâmetros comuns da função, não em formato de array
  - Confiro se o número retornado do `Math.min` é finito com o `isFinite` pois caso o array vá vazio para o `Math.min` ele retorna um `Infinity`
  - Depois é só alertar uma mensagem com o menor número ou pedindo para informar pelo menos um número para não responder `Infinity` como menor número

```js
var button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {

  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=number]');
  var valores = [];

 for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      valores.push(parseFloat(inputs[i].value));
  }
  
  valores = valores.filter(function(valor) {
   return !isNaN(valor) && valor > 0;
  });
  
  var menorNumero = Math.min.apply({}, valores);
  
 var mensagem = 'Informe pelo menos um número';
  
  if(isFinite(menorNumero)) {
   mensagem = 'O menor número é ' + menorNumero;
  }
  
  alert(mensagem);

});
```

```html
<input type="number" /> <br />
<input type="number" /> <br />
<input type="number" /> <br />

<button type="button">
  Pegar menor número
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seguinte o código Lucas, função `verificar` dele está sem reiniciar variável é necessário zerar o valor para aplicar recomeçar, e segue o código abaixo esta corrigido.

```js
function verificar(){
  var campo = document.querySelectorAll("input");
  var valores = [];
  campo.forEach(item =>{
      if (!item.value) item.value = 0;
      valores.push(parseFloat(item.value));
  });
  console.log(valores.sort()[0]);
  //ou pode ser abaixo lucas postaram
  //console.log(Math.min.apply(null, valores));
}
```

```html
<input type="text"/><br/>
<input type="text"/><br/>
<input type="text"/><br/>
<button onclick="verificar()">Verificar</button>
```

Histórico (Lucas):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bt8So.png

Answer (score 1):

como você disse está usando uma mascara `jQuery` para formatar o valor e adicionar o `R$`, então deve de está utilizando a `jQuery MaskMoney`.

Então a primeira coisa a fazer, é usar o método `.maskMoney('unmasked')` obter todos os `valores`, então realize um filtro (você pode usar o `Array.prototype.filter` para isto) para ignorar os valores abaixo de zero, por fim chame o `Math.min`.

No exemplo abaixo, caso não informe nenhum valor, o `Math.min` irá retornar `infinito`.

```js
var inputsMoney = $("input[data-money]");
inputsMoney.maskMoney();

$("#btMenorValor").on("click", function () {
  var valores = inputsMoney.maskMoney('unmasked');
  var valores = [].filter.call(valores, function (numero, indice) {
    return numero > 0;
  })
  console.log(Math.min.apply(null, valores));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-maskmoney/3.0.2/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <label>
    Valor: 
    <input type="text" data-money data-affixes-stay="true" data-prefix="R$ " data-thousands="." data-decimal="," />
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>
    Valor: 
    <input type="text" data-money data-affixes-stay="true" data-prefix="R$ " data-thousands="." data-decimal="," />
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>
    Valor: 
    <input type="text" data-money data-affixes-stay="true" data-prefix="R$ " data-thousands="." data-decimal="," />
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>
    Valor: 
    <input type="text" data-money data-affixes-stay="true" data-prefix="R$ " data-thousands="." data-decimal="," />
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>
    Valor: 
    <input type="text" data-money data-affixes-stay="true" data-prefix="R$ " data-thousands="." data-decimal="," />
  </label>
</div>
<input id="btMenorValor" type="button" value="Menor Valor" />
```